# Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser with SQL Server Express and Docker Container

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, localhost

I'm working on a web app with ASP.NET Core using Docker container for the app and SQL Server Express for the local server. I can create the migration and update the database without any issue, so I know my connection string is working and is accessible.

- I made sure that SQL Server Express server browser is running SQL Server Configuration Manager and Services.
- I have enabled TCP/IP on port 1433 for `SQLEXPRESS`.
- I've made sure that my link was working properly by using wrong connection string to see if the result was different.

I saw somewhere that the Docker container could be the reason that the server is not accessible but I'm not sure how I could fix that if that's the case.

> ExtendedSocketException: Name or service not known
>
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(string hostName, bool justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, ValueStopwatch stopwatch)
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(string hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family)
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(string hostNameOrAddress)
> System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.GetEndpoint(string hostname, int port)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.SendUDPRequest(string browserHostname, int port, byte[] requestPacket)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName(string browserHostName, string instanceName)

> Exception: Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName(string browserHostName, string instanceName)

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle(DataSource details, long timerExpire, bool parallel, string cachedFQDN, ref SQLDNSInfo pendingDNSInfo)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateConnectionHandle(string fullServerName, bool ignoreSniOpenTimeout, long timerExpire, out byte[] instanceName, ref byte[][] spnBuffer, bool flushCache, bool async, bool parallel, bool isIntegratedSecurity, string cachedFQDN, ref SQLDNSInfo pendingDNSInfo)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(string serverName, bool ignoreSniOpenTimeout, long timerExpire, out byte[] instanceName, ref byte[][] spnBuffer, bool flushCache, bool async, bool parallel, string cachedFQDN, ref SQLDNSInfo pendingDNSInfo, bool isIntegratedSecurity)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, bool ignoreSniOpenTimeout, long timerExpire, bool encrypt, bool trustServerCert, bool integratedSecurity, bool withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, bool withFailover)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling, string accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool errorsExpected)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> MyBusiness.Controllers.CustomersController.Index() in F:\Projet\MyProject
> \Controllers\CustomersController.cs
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIAct  ionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
> System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask actionResultValueTask)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**EDIT**
As asked, here is the connection string

```
LocalConnection": "data source=DESKTOP-XXXX\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MYBUSINESS;trusted_connection=true"
```

I've tried to replace `DESKTOP-XXXX\\SQLEXPRESS;` with `host.docker.internal;` and `host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS;` but bith didn't work

dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyBusiness/MyBusiness.csproj", "MyBusiness/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyBusiness/MyBusiness.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BainMMyBusinessgique"
RUN dotnet build "MyBusiness.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyBusiness.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyBusiness.dll"]
```

Comment: Show your docker file

Comment: So show your docker file

Comment: If the ASP.NET Core application is running in a Docker container then what connection properties are in its connection string? It cannot connect to `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` nor `::1` because all of those addresses refer to the container itself - and the SQL Server Browser service is running on the Docker host. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73668889/edit) your question to include the connection string.

Comment: use host.docker.internal in connection string instead of localhost

Comment: Looks like you are getting a proxy error. Probably getting a credential error.  You can check the SQL Logs by opening SQL Server Management Studio and checking the logs under the Management Tab which will tell what credentials were being used.  You should be using in the connection string Integrated Security=true which is using Windows Credentials.  Then asp.net should be using Authentication while will pass the client window credentials to the asp.net server : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs

Comment: check this [article](https://medium.com/@vedkoditkar/connect-to-local-ms-sql-server-from-docker-container-9d2b3d33e5e9)

Comment: @CodingMytra I did what was in the article and changed my Connection string to

`"LocalConnection": "Server=host.docker.internal, 1433;initial catalog=MYDB;trusted_connection=true"`

and

`"LocalConnection": "data source=host.docker.internal;initial catalog=MYDB;trusted_connection=true"`

But both didn't work. I actually get a crash of my web app